# JQuery Ajax fills javascript variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to fill a variable in this format using JQuery Ajax but because of all the brackets, I am unable to return the data in the format from the backend

```
elements = [{ 
    key: 1, 
    label: "Food", 
    open: false, 
    children: [
        { key: 211, label: "Burger" }
    ]
}];
```

Here is the code I am currently using which isn't working

menu.aspx:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "menu.aspx/get_menu",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#test").html(msg.d);
    }
});
```

backend:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public static string get_menu()
{
    return "hello world";
}
```

Comment: You are returning a string, not JSON. Try `$("#test").html(msg);`

Comment: Separately, if you specify `contentType` on your `$.ajax` call, you're responsible for serializing the data you're sending from the client to the server in that form (e.g., you can't do `data: {}`). jQuery only does serialization for you with the standard URI-encoded form. Unless you're *sending* JSON to the server, remove `contentType: "application/json"`.

Comment: Your backend script surely won't give you the data you expect, only "hello world" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend code should look something more like this (WebService.cs in my example, which is the CodeBehind for WebService.asmx ):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public class JsonResult
    {
        public string key, label, open;
        public List<Children> children;
    }
    public class Children
    {
        public string key, label;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<JsonResult> test()
    {
        List<Children> child = new List<Children>();
        child.Add(new Children
        {
            key = "211",
            label = "Burger"
        });

        List<JsonResult> result = new List<JsonResult>();
        result.Add(new JsonResult
        {
            key = "1",
            label = "Food",
            open = "false",
            children = child
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

This code sends the created list as JSON - which looks like this when jQuery receives it:

```
{"d":[
    {
        "__type":"WebService+JsonResult",
        "key":"1",
        "label":"Food",
        "open":"false",
        "children":[
            {
                "key":"211",
                "label":"Burger"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Then, the jQuery AJAX is very simple, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/WebService.asmx/test",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        var jsonResponse = response.d;
    }
});
```

Now you can access each element as native JavaScript objects, like I show here in the `success` callback when assigning each object to a variable.  Now you can do anything you want to with the data.

```
success: function (response) {
    var jsonResponse = response.d;
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
        var key = jsonResponse[i].key;
        var label = jsonResponse[i].label;
        var open = jsonResponse[i].open;
        var children = jsonResponse[i].children;
        for (var a = 0; a < children.length; a++) {
            var key = children[a].key;
            var label = children[a].label;
        }
    }
}
```

This is 100% tested and working.  Let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.