# How to pass javascript object into c# web service with c# object as a parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

So basically I have a C# web method that I will call via ajax. The C# paramter is a simple KeyValue object, that looks like this:

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and in my javascript I have created a hash that has a key value pair structure.

```
var updateSettingsHash = [];
```

this is where it's initialized, and then I add to it later using .Add, and following a key/value format for the array (so it's acting like a dictionary).

So my question is now, I have a C# webmethod that accepts a parameter List

```
[WebMethod]
    public ServiceResult SaveConfigurationValuesForPrivateLabel(List<KeyValue> settings)
```

So really 2 questions. A) How do I pass in a List using ajax? Since there is no lists in javascript? and B) How do I use the class KeyValue in javascript to create instances and be able to create a list of them?

Comment: The list can be represented with an anonymous object in javascript ( var list = [ { Key = "ABC", Value = "DEF" }, { Key = "ZZZ", Value = "YYY" } ]; ).  Then, serialized as json for transmitting to asp.net

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but still trying to figure out how to pass in C# classes into javascript ajax call.

Comment: See if my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446435/jquery-ajax-fills-javascript-variable-issue/27449243#27449243) helps you at all.  It's a little more in-depth than what you are looking for, but should get you on the right track.  Let me know if you have any more questions after, and I'll do my best to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of javascript objects and using for example jquery call the webmethod like this:

```
var settingsList= [{Key: 'a', Value: 'A'}, {Key: 'b', Value: 'B'}, {Key: 'c', Value: 'C'}];
var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ settings: settingsList});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "WebService1.asmx/SaveConfigurationValuesForPrivateLabel",
  data: jsonText,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function() { alert("it worked"); },
  failure: function() { alert("Something's wrong"); }
});
```

As for directly using a C# class in javascript, I don't think it's possible, you can either use anonymous object like shown above or create an object prototype like this:

```
function KeyValue(Key, Value){
   this.Key = Key;
   this.Value = Value;
}

var keyValuePair = new KeyValue('x', 'X');
```